# Passing a list of key-value pairs in Python requests

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am trying to post some parameters to server using REST. I am trying to craft a request of what the following url achieves.

https://example.com/rest/server.php?var[0][a]=1&var[0][b]=23

what I am trying is the following, but it does not work.

```
params =  {"var": [{'a':1, 'b':23}]}
resp = requests.post("https://example.com/rest/server.php",
                    data = json.dumps(params))
```

I see that in the request.body, the parameters are passed like below

```
{"var": [{"a": 1, "b": 23}]}
```

Comment: `resp = requests.post("https://example.com/rest/server.php", params={'var[0][a]': 1, 'var[0][b]': 23})`

Comment: @well that works, thanks. Though I was wondering whether a modular approach exists.

Comment: You are free to implement something to generate the keys. But the complexity in this case comes from the less beautiful query schema defined by the server.

Comment: @KlausD. I guess you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you tell it to do, which is:

- Use POST parameters instead of GET,
- Format the parameter data as json.

Instead, you want to use GET parameters, formatted in a non-standard way.

Perhaps something like this might help you forther:

```
def encode_params(params, head = None):
    output = []
    if head is None:
        head = ''
    if isinstance(params, dict):
        for k,v in params.items():
            output.extend(encode_params(v, '%s[%s]' % (head,k)))
    elif isinstance(params, list) or isinstance(params, tuple):
        for k,v in enumerate(params):
            output.extend(encode_params(v, '%s[%s]' % (head,k)))
    else:
        return ['%s=%r' % (head, params)]

    return output

encoded_args = ','.join([','.join(encode_params(v, k)) for k,v in params.items()])
```

It can definitely be improved further, but this might give you a head start. You will need to add some sanity checks, like `urllib.parse.quote_plus(...)` or something that prevents args like '][' to be added directly.

Comment: Not exactly right, almost there, but I got the idea and fixed it, thanks.